# Android Studio new project gradle sync fail

Tags: android, gradle

I recently updated android studio to 3.1.2 version and kotlin plugin to 2.41 and had the android support repository downloaded.

Since then i have been unable to create new projects.when i try to sync the gradle i get these:

```
-Failed to resolve: constraint-layout  
-Failed to resolve: constraint-layout-solver  
-Failed to resolve: viewmodel  
-Failed to resolve: runtime  
-Failed to resolve: livedata-core  
-Failed to resolve: common
```

I sensed the problem may be failing to download from maven so i tried adding lines like:
`maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}`
but no luck.then i changed the implementation in my module:app gradle file from

```
 `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1`
```

to

```
`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`
```

(which was the downloaded version mentioned in my sdk manager)

which resulted in this error:

```
-Could not find viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/viewmodel/1.1.0/viewmodel-1.1.0.aar
```

which is funny because when i click on the link above a viewmodel-1.1.0.aar is downloaded!

What should i do to successfully sync the gradle?

Here is the app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohamad.arkotlin"
        minSdkVersion 'P'
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and the project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you please add both Gradle files?

Comment: i added the gradle files

Comment: Okay so that url you added is the same as `google()`, so that's why it didn't fix anything

Comment: what url should i add?

Comment: As you said *so i tried adding lines like:
`maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}`*.. But adding it doesn't help because having `google()`  line is the exact same thing

Comment: ok.but still not helping.how should i fix this problem?

Comment: Are you able to run `./gradlew clean build` from the project directory in a terminal? If that fails, the problem is not Android Studio, it's actually Gradle

Comment: deleted AS and all my gradle folders.installed it again and now its working.thanks for the help tho